# over-ride a method in extended class in node js and access variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop, prototypal-inheritance

How can I access parent prototype variable 'id' in child prototype.

```
const util = require('util');

const Parent = function () {};

Parent.prototype.access = function() {
    var id = 1;
};

const Child = function () {};

util.inherits(Child, Parent);

child.prototype.access = function() {
    //access Parent.prototype.access variable 'id' here
}
```

Any Thoughts??

Comment: You can't. `id` is only existent within the scope of the parent function. Set it up on the instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using JS Classes.

```
class Parent {
  constructor(id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  access() {
    this.id = 1;
    console.log('Parent access');
  }
}

class Child extends Parent {
  access() {
    console.log(`Child access: ${this.id}`);
  }
}

const d = new Child(5);
d.access(); // Child access: 5
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I need to implement using prototypal inheritance only, cannot use JS classes.